# How can I figure out the the limit of the following sequence?

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, analysis

I am looking for the limit of the following sequence:

$((2-2i)/3)^n \ $

I know you can also write it this way:

$(2/3*(1-i))^n = (2/3)^n * (1-i)^n \ $

But I have no idea how to proceed from there on and how to figure out if the sequence converges or diverges if $n\to ∞ $

Comment: What is $|(2-2i)/3|$?

Comment: That's not what I get ....

Comment: Oh, hold on, should it not be the (root of (8)) /3 then?

Comment: Indeed, anyway that's less than $1$.

Comment: So, can i say that the limit of the sequence has to be 0, right? Since it it is a geometric sequence and as far as i know, the limit has to be 0 if |q| <1? Is that way of reasoning correct?

Comment: It's a sequence $(a^n)$ with $|a|<1$. Such sequences converge to zero.

Comment: I did not see that, thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$|(2-2i)/3|
=\sqrt{4/9+4/9}
=\sqrt{8/9}
\lt 1
$
so
$|((2-2i)/3)^n|
=\sqrt{8/9}^n
\to 0
$.

Answer (score 0):

Write it in exponential form:
$$\frac23(1-i)=\frac {2\sqrt2}3\,\mathrm e^{-\tfrac{i\pi}4},$$
so you have a geometric sequence  with a complex ratio of modulus $<1$.

Comment: Yes. I definitely should check my calculations at the end of day…